# VueJS: v-for with dynamic component strange behavior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following syntax inside one of my components:

```
<event-item v-for='(event, index) in events'
            :is='eventComponent(event)'
            :key="'event-' + index"
            :event='event'>
</event-item>
```

The list is rendered correctly at the first moment.

However, when I add a new element to the events array using *events.unshift(event)*, a strange behavior happens: the event-item component for the event with index **n** is rendered using some of the properties of the event with index **n+1**.

This behavior also does not occur if I use *events.push(event)*, but using it is not an option because I need to insert the new events at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the `key` you are using and the fact you are `unshift`ing items out of the array. Because that key has been used, the component won't re-render.

You have 2 options:

1. Change your key so it contains an ID of event (I would recommend this approach). You can generate an ID using a Guid or something.
2. Clear the array and re-build it (wasteful IMO)

I personally have a `uuid` package in my projects but you could do something like:

`event.id = '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)`

then in the component `v-for` loop: `:key="event.id"`

Comment: Exactly! Thank you :)